# How to config vim to open a filename which contains line and column number?

Tags: vim

It's usefull, when debug a program.

```
# compile file
$ g++ -Wall main.cpp
main.cpp:42:7: warning: backslash and newline separated by space

# I do this to locate
$ vim main.cpp +42 +'normal 7|'

# how to do this?
$ vim main.cpp:42:7:
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [file:line](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2184) plugin also. 
It will open file and set cursor position to specified line and column.

Works with trailing colon:

```
vim file.cpp:10
vim file.cpp:10:
vim file.cpp:10:4
vim file.cpp:10:4:
```

Answer (score 4):

vim actually has a whole set of built-in commands and options for this.

You get the documentation with

```
:help quickfix
```

For example

```
:set makeprg=g++\ -Wall\ main.cc " the default is make
:make
```

will parse the errors and warnings output by g++ and let you cycle through the locations.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the "quickfix" features of vim: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix

You can compile from within vim (see vim's `makeprg` and `errorformat` variables), and then automatically jump to the lines that generate errors using `:cc`, `:cp`, and `:cn`.

The same vimdoc shows you how to jump quickly to the beginning or end of the current function or block of code, and if you use `ctags` you can also locate the definitions of functions and variables.